# Rcpp function: f(x) - f(x) is not 0

Tags: r, rcpp

I rewrote a pure R function using Rcpp for reasons of computation speed.

Here is the function:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double es_loss_c(NumericVector b, NumericVector Y, NumericMatrix X, double alpha, double delta) {

  int n = X.nrow();                           // Number of observations
  int k = X.ncol();                           // Number of parameters

  NumericVector b_q = b[Range(0, k-1)];       // Quantile parameters
  NumericVector b_e = b[Range(k, 2*k-1)];     // Expected shortfall parameters

  // Initialize required variables
  NumericVector Xi;
  double out, Yi, Xb_q, Xb_e, u, exp_e, H;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    Yi = Y(i);
    Xi = X(i,_);

    // Pre-store some values
    Xb_q = sum(Xi * b_q);
    Xb_e = sum(Xi * b_e);

    u = Yi - Xb_q;
    exp_e = exp(Xb_e);

    // Indicator function or its approximation
    if (delta > 0) {
      H = 1 / (1 + exp(delta * u));
    } else {
      H = u <= 0;
    }

    // Shortfall loss
    out += (alpha - H) * u + exp_e / (1 + exp_e) * (-1/alpha * H * u + Xb_e - Xb_q) - log(1 + exp_e);
  }

  return out / n;
}
```

You can test the function with:

```
set.seed(1)
X <- cbind(1, rnorm(1000))
Y <- X %*% c(0, 1) + rnorm(1000)
b0 <- rnorm(4)
es_loss_c(b0, Y, X, 0.01, 100)
[1] 64.22035
```

This works so far and the result is the same (up to 1e-15) as with the pure R implementation.

But then, something really strange happens:

```
es_loss_c(b0, Y, X, 0.01, 100) - es_loss_c(b0, Y, X, 0.01, 100)
[1] -64.22035
es_loss_c(b0, Y, X, 0.01, 100) + es_loss_c(b0, Y, X, 0.01, 100)
[1] 192.6611
es_loss_c(b0, Y, X, 0.01, 100) / es_loss_c(b0, Y, X, 0.01, 100)
[1] 0.5
```

Can you explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: "I rewrote a pure R function" -> which base R function was it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `out = 0;` before using it. Just add it before `for` loop and each call to `es_loss_c` will produce identical results.